# Getting Data from Differential Equation Solution

Tags: differential-equations

I am solving the following differential equation. I need to get the values of `y[x]` for `x` ranging from 1 to 30. I need to get this data into excel. How can I extract it from *Mathematica* ?

```
Stefan = 0.6929;
s = NDSolve[{y'[
     x] == (Stefan*((x/2) - (((x^2) - 1)/(4*x*Log[x])))) + (x*Log[x]),
    y[1.00000001] == 0}, y[x], x]
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

All your answers are right there in the documentation:

If you look into the `NDSolve` help, the first example gives you the correct way of writing the code. For your problem:

```
Stefan = 0.6929; 
s = NDSolve[{y'[x] == (Stefan*((x/2) - (((x^2) - 1)/(4*x Log[x])))) + (x Log[x]),y[1.00000001] == 0}, y[x], {x, 1, 30}];
```

You can form the data list using the command `Table`:

```
val = Table[Evaluate[y[x] /. s], {x, 1, 30}]
```

You can export the data to excel using the command `Export`:

```
Export["data.xls", val]
```

Comment: @Shaunak. Get very friendly with the *Mathematica* documentation, as suggested in this answer!

Comment: Yes I just checked the documentation ! Thank you very much Saurav and march.